# js-doc merging new properties into existing object type

Tags: material-ui, jsdoc, jsdoc3

I am using material-ui in react project and I created some new button variants `ribbon`, `ribbon-filled` and `ribbon-text` in the theme like stated in their [docs](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/theme-components/#creating-new-component-variants). I have written a custom react component that utilizes material-ui Button component. I have merged props received in this component with material UI's `ButtonProps`. In addition to merging, I also want to patch specific Material UI's object 'types' with new properties. Precisely, I want to add new variants to the Material UI's button variants. Here is the code for this component:

```js
// CustomBtn.jsx
/**
 * @typedef {import("react").JSX.Element} ReactElement
 * @typedef {import("@mui/material").ButtonProps} MuiBtnProps
 */

/**
 * @typedef {object} MyBtnProps
 * @property {string} [title] - Title to show on floating menu
 * @property {string} [text] - Text to dispaly in the button
 * @property {(function | ReactElement)} renderMenu - The content to show on the floating Menu.
 * @property {function} [onClose] - Function called when menu closes
 *
 * @typedef {MuiBtnProps & MyBtnProps} MyCustomBtnProps
 */

/**
 * Renders Button with a controlled a floating menu
 * @param {MyCustomBtnProps} props
 * @returns {ReactElement}
 */
const CustomBtn = (props) => {
  const {
    text,
    renderMenu,
    title,
    onClose,
    children,
    ...rest
  } = props;

  const ariaDesc = "open-popup-menu";

  const handleTriggerMenu = () => {
    // ...
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Button
        aria-describedby={ariaDesc}
        variant="ribbon"
        onClick={handleTriggerMenu}
        size="small"
        {...rest}
      >
        {text || children}
      </Button>

      // Other code ...
    </>
  );
};
```

When using this custom button, intellisense works in VS Code. The problem I have is: Intellisense is only aware of variants coming from Material-ui, i.e my variants as stated above do not appear in suggestions:[image: VS Code intellisense when using my CustomBtn]

I have tried to modify `MyBtnProps` in the jsDoc comments like this:

```js
// ...
/**
 * @typedef {object} MyBtnProps
 * @property {string} [title] - Title to show on floating menu
 * @property {string} [text] - Text to dispaly in the button
 * @property {("ribbon"|"ribbon-filled"|"ribbon-text")} [variant] - Button variant
 * @property {(Function | ReactElement)} renderMenu - The content to show on the floating Menu.
 * @property {function} [onClose] - Function called when menu closes
 *
 * @typedef {MuiBtnProps & MyBtnProps} MyCustomBtnProps
 */
// ...
```

The change made is: I added the line `@property {("ribbon"|"ribbon-filled"|"ribbon-text")} [variant] - Button variant`. I expected this to merge new variants given here with what Material UI has. Instead this resulted in me getting no intellisense at all(when utilizing my `CustomBtn` in another file).

Is there a way I can get my created variants to appear alongside Material UI's variants in VS Code intellisense?

**Just to be clear**, the project does not use Typescript. So using jsDoc comments to document components is a viable option.